# Why is it non-obvious that $f$ satisfies the elementary row properties

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am reading a proof of the property $\det (A\cdotp B) = \det (A) \cdotp \det (B)$.
It starts by defining $f(A)=\det (A \cdotp B)$. Then it states "We shall first prove that $f$ satisfies the elementary row properties of the determinant function.

As $f$ is the determinant function, is it not obvious that it satisfies the elementary row properties?

Comment: But $f$ is not "the determinant function." Specifically, the function $g(A) = \det(A)$ satisfies the properties, but it is not immediate that $f(A) = \det(A B)$ does.

Comment: @angryavian But $AB$ is also a matrixIf $g(C)=det(C)$, does $f$ not satisfy the properties regardless of whether $C=A$, $C=B$, or $C=AB$?

Comment: We need here to use the associativity property of matrix multiplication, to show this.

Comment: @clark The author of the proof considers each elementary row operation individually. But my question is why this even has to be considered at all? I must be missing something because it seems evident to me, given that $AB$ is a matrix just like $A$ is.

Comment: @JohnArg If you swap two rows in $A$, is it obvious that $\det(A.B)$ changes its sign ?

Comment: @rsadhvika Ohhh, nope it's not. Thanks!

Comment: "We shall first prove that f satisfies the elementary row properties of the determinant function". By that he wants to show that if you start with a matrix $A$ and you obtain $\tilde{A}$ after applying elementary row operations, then $f(A)=f(\tilde{A})$ or $\text{det}(AB)=\text{det}(\tilde{A}B) $.